# Why OpenCV projectpoints function showing weird values?

Tags: c++, opencv

I created rotation and translation matrix from decomposing the essential matrix and use cv::Rodrigues function to create the rotation vector. But using projectPoints showing some very weird values, e.g., values like 1.00e10, etc. Can anyone please give a hint why this might occur?

I am using visual studio 2012 and build version of opencv vs11.

```
Matx34d P1 = Matx34d(R1(0,0),   R1(0,1),    R1(0,2),    t1(0),
                     R1(1,0),   R1(1,1),    R1(1,2),    t1(1),
                     R1(2,0),   R1(2,1),    R1(2,2),    t1(2)); 

vector<double> reproj_error1, reproj_error2;
unsigned int pts_size = good_matches.size();        

//undistort
Mat pt_set1_pt,pt_set2_pt;
undistortPoints(matchedpoints1, pt_set1_pt, K, distcoeff);
undistortPoints(matchedpoints2, pt_set2_pt, K, distcoeff);  

//triangulate
Mat pt_set1_pt_2r = pt_set1_pt.reshape(1, 2);
Mat pt_set2_pt_2r = pt_set2_pt.reshape(1, 2);
Mat pt_3d_h(1,pts_size,CV_32FC1);
cv::triangulatePoints(P1,P2,pt_set1_pt_2r,pt_set2_pt_2r,pt_3d_h);

vector<Point3f> pt_3d;
convertPointsHomogeneous(pt_3d_h.reshape(4, 1), pt_3d);
cv::Mat_<double> R = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << P1(0,0),P1(0,1),P1(0,2), P1(1,0),P1(1,1),P1(1,2), P1(2,0),P1(2,1),P1(2,2));
court << R << endl;

cv::Mat rvec(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
cv::Mat tvec(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    
tvec = (Mat_<double>(3,1) <<P1(0,3),P1(1,3),P1(2,3));
cv::Rodrigues(R,rvec);
  
Rodrigues(R ,rvec);

vector<Point2f> reprojected_pt_set1;
cv::projectPoints(pt_3d,rvec,tvec,K,distcoeff,reprojected_pt_set1);
```

The values of rvec = `[-0.92863;0.30439;0.21210]` and tvec = `[-0.309466;-2.16395;0.03796]`.

Comment: Post your code and results.

Comment: Can you post some of the points to be projected? and which K are you using, can you post it as well?

Comment: K=[1000 0 500;0 1000 500;0 0 1];

Comment: K=[1000 0 500;0 1000 500;0 0 1]; one of the points is P = [1.06 1.01 .94] whose projected value I get is [705254528,-552603520]

Comment: Do you use any distcoeff? I am getting with those numbers provided and for that point : {x=-439.7 y=1856.0 } which still is out of a picture frame but it is more normal result....Maybe you can pass in this position cv::noArray() to see if you get something better.